# How to solve this error when running 'yarn start'?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

I am trying to run a project that is bootstrapped with react app:
https://github.com/dcbuild3r/ethgaswatch

When I try to run the app in development mode using 'yarn start' in terminal I get the following:

```
PS C:\Users\alaiy\Documents\Projects\Python\ethgaswatch\web> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.17
warning package.json: No license field
$ concurrently 'react-scripts start' 'netlify-lambda serve src/functions'
[0] ''react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
[0] operable program or batch file.
[1] 'start'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[2] ''netlify-lambda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2] operable program or batch file.
[3] 'serve' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[3] operable program or batch file.
[4] 'src' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[4] operable program or batch file.
[2] 'netlify-lambda exited with code 1
[1] start' exited with code 1
[0] 'react-scripts exited with code 1 
[4] src/functions' exited with code 1 
[3] serve exited with code 1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've not had this issue before when using yarn start so not sure what I'm doing wrong. As far as I know, I have installed the dependencies through npm.

I have read the concurrently docs. Now rather than running `yarn start`, if i run `concurrently 'react-scripts start' 'netlify-lambda serve src/functions'` in terminal i still get the same error however now my error does not contain the extra quote at the start.

```
PS C:\Users\alaiy\Documents\Projects\Python\ethgaswatch\web> concurrently 'react-scripts start' 'netlify-lambda serve src/functions'
[0] 'react-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[0] react-scripts start exited with code 1
[1] 'netlify-lambda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[1] netlify-lambda serve src/functions exited with code 1
```

Comment: If this was linux I would guess you'd set PATH=/usr/bin:/bin , so `which react-scripts` won't find it in your path. But then "start" is an argument, so it's curious that yarn would attempt to fork&exec it.

Comment: @J_H I've added the github repo i'm using if it helps

Answer (score 0):

OIC.

I am reading this "scripts" line:

https://github.com/dcbuild3r/ethgaswatch/blob/b94ca/web/package.json#L7

```
    "start": "concurrently 'react-scripts start' 'netlify-lambda serve src/functions'",
```

You asked [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to fork off a pair of programs.
But you asked badly, and it didn't go well.

I imagine that on some linux & mac systems we wind up passing args to `bash`,
which does a layer of quote interpretation.
On your system it appears that didn't happen.
What *did* happen is concurrently tried running a program
named `'react-scripts`, where the program name starts with a quote.
You don't have such a program, so predictably it failed.
Similarly for `start'` and the rest of the train wreck.

tl;dr: "quoting nonsense!"

Comment: I am not the code's author. I don't know what environment he intended it to run in. I suspect that running on mac or linux would produce different results from running on windows. As a kludgey approach, you might consider creating a pair of one-liners rs_start.bat & nl_serve.bat in your PATH, so no troublesome quotes will be involved.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I tried running the concurrently command separately and it still gives the error however it does not add the quote at the start. See the original post as i've added this. Thanks for pointing this out though!

Answer (score 0):

You have react-scripts --saved by default after you have used CRA. So you do not need to re-save it. If npm install (with or without deleting node_modules) doesn't fix the issue, the problem is likely with an old version of NPM or a problem with PATH which can be fixed as per my answe

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).